# Order fullfillment Optimization Algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, magento

I am working on one module in Magento where I need to work on 100% order fullfillment optimization for example:

In Stock, we have the below products:

```
Product1    - 2 (Qty in stock)
Product2    - 2
Product3    - 3
Product4    - 5
```

and In Store, we have the below Orders that we need to prepare for shipping:

```
Order1      -   Product1    - 1 (Ordered Qty)
                Product2    - 2
                Product3    - 1
                Product4    - 4

Order2      -   Product2    - 2
                Product4    - 1

Order3      -   Product1    - 1 
                Product3    - 2
                Product4    - 4
```

If I will start picking the Products for orders from Top to bottom like below:

> Case 1 for assignment of Products to Orders

```
Order1      -   Product1    - 1 (Ordered Qty)   -  1 (Assigned Qty from Stock)
                Product2    - 2                 -  2
                Product3    - 1                 -  1
                Product4    - 4                 -  4

Order2      -   Product2    - 2 (Ordered Qty)   -  0 (No Stock Remain)
                Product4    - 1                 -  1 

Order3      -   Product1    - 1 (Ordered Qty)   -  1 
                Product3    - 2                 -  2 
                Product4    - 4                 -  0 (No Stock Remain)
```

But If I will start picking the Products for orders from Bottom to like below:

> Case 2 for assignment of Products to Orders

```
Order1      -   Product1    - 1 (Ordered Qty)   -  1 (Assigned Qty from Stock)
                Product2    - 2                 -  0 (No Stock Remain)
                Product3    - 1                 -  1 (Short Picked) 
                Product4    - 4                 -  0 (No Stock Remain)

Order2      -   Product2    - 2 (Ordered Qty)   -  2 (Assigned Qty from Stock) 
                Product4    - 1                 -  1 

Order3      -   Product1    - 1 (Ordered Qty)   -  1 (Assigned Qty from Stock)
                Product3    - 2                 -  2 
                Product4    - 4                 -  4
```

As you can see the In `Case 1`, we are only getting 33% complete order fullfillment and remaining 66% orders are not completed fully. But In `Case 2`  we are only getting 66% complete order fullfillment and remaining 33% orders are not completed fully.

For example purpose, we have taken top to bottom and bottom to top approach but it can process in any way to get maximum order completion percentage.

If anyone have worked on such type of problem previously, Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Good news** your problem can be modelized as an [Integer Programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) quite easily:

Input: Let `S(j)` be the stock of product `j` and let `o(i,j)` be the quantity of product `j` in order `i`.

Variables:
Let `x(i)` be equal to `1` if the order is done and `0` otherwise.

Formulation: you want to solve the following problem:

`max sum x(i)`

`s.t.` `sum ( o(i,j) x(i) ) <= s(j)` for any `j`

**Bad news** is that solving this type of problem is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) and hence there is no known polynomial algorithm to solve this problem to optimality. So you'll have to solve it in an approximative way with a heuristic, for example by sorting the orders by numbers of items they need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sharing link. let me try your shared solution